# TypeScript writing d.ts file for module that can be instantiate

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I having problem creating declaration file for an existing module.

When using javascript the module imported using syntax:

```
var Library = require('thirdpartylibs');
var libInstance = new Library();
```

i have created d.ts file called `thirdpartylibs.d.ts` and add the following:

```
declare module 'thirdpartylibs'{
   export class Library{}
}
```

in my `index.ts` file :

```
import * as Library from 'thirdpartylibs'
let libInstance = new Library() // <--- error here
```

seems like i should do `let libInstance = new Library.Library()` to make it work, but it will fail on the generated JS.

anyone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
declare module 'thirdpartylibs'{
   class Library {
      ...
   }
   export = Library
}
```

To import

```
import Library = require('thirdpartylibs')
const libInstance = new Library()
```

Note: this makes `Library` *the* export. The syntax you were using is a "named export"

Comment: thanks for replying by using your solution I got `Module ''thirdpartylibs'' resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct.`. any clue?

Comment: try `import Library = require('thirdpartylibs')`. (note: `import`, not `const`. Typings should be available)

Comment: @kulaka edited my answer (although `import * as...` seems t work with TS 2.0, not 1.8)

Comment: curious why doesn't it work with `import * as Library from '......'` ? what is the correct way to do declaration such like above?

Comment: `import * as X from 'x'` is an ES6 import syntax. ES6 import syntax only let you import modules. When simply importing a Class or Function, this syntax cannot be used. Yet there is a way of 'tricking' it by adding an empty namespace declaration in the `d.ts`: `namespace Library{}`